# Where to place initialisation code in Firebase cloud functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

We are planning to use [express-ajv-swagger-validation](https://github.com/Zooz/express-ajv-swagger-validation)
middleware to validate our api requests.

But I see it has a async function for initialisation and would like to know where i can init with the swagger json file.

If it do init on every request, I see it too heavy. So, can someone share how to achieve "init once and use forever" ?

Below is the example on how to use it currently. How can I load once and store it in memory so that it won't validate everytime?

```
swaggerValidator.init('test/unit-tests/input-validation/pet-store-swagger.yaml')
.then(function () {
    const app = express();
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.get('/pets', swaggerValidator.validate, function (req, res, next) {
        return res.json({ result: 'OK' });
    });
    app.post('/pets', swaggerValidator.validate, function (req, res, next) {
        return res.json({ result: 'OK' });
    });
    app.get('/pets/:petId', swaggerValidator.validate, function (req, res, next) {
        return res.json({ result: 'OK' });
    });

    app.use(function (err, req, res) {
        if (err instanceof swaggerValidator.InputValidationError) {
            return res.status(400).json({ more_info: JSON.stringify(err.errors) });
        }
    });

   // const server = app.listen(serverPort, function () {});
});
```

Comment: What do you intend to do with the results of this initialization?  What's your final destination here?

Comment: swaggerValidator takes the schema and is required to validate all my requests.

For instance, if /pets request comes in as a request,  swaggerValidator.validate will check  the corresponding request spec and validates if all the query parameters, body are proper as per swagger specification. If not, it throws an error.

Basically for validating the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your code at the global scope.  Since it's asynchronous, it returns a promise that you can use in your function that will ensure that it's ready to use.

At the global scope:

```
const promise = swaggerValidator.init(...).then(...)
```

Then, inside your function:

```
promise.then(() => {
    // use swaggerValidator
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Doug. Won't this init on every request it encounters?

Comment: No, it won't.  Use debug logging to verify for yourself.  It will only run once at the global scope for each function for each time it gets allocated in a new server instance.

Comment: so I can use something like this right?
const promise = swaggerValidator.init('swagger-file-path');

router.get("/pets", validate, controller.get);

....
async function validate(req, res, next) {
await promise;
}

Comment: That's pretty much what I said in my answer, right?

Comment: "for each time it gets allocated in a new server instance" - A bit confused with this. Won't this mean for every request it gets initialised for every server spin up or one time per function forever?

Comment: That's pretty much what I said in my answer, right? - Yes, you meant the same. Just confirming. Please don't mind :)

Comment: No, that's not what it means.  You should watch this video series to understand how Cloud Functions and other serverless backends work: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2mjfI0FYP7Y&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLm9A9rcHb1IkyQUu6QwbjdM

Comment: Perfect Doug! Straight to the point! Thanks alot :). I love your videos :)

Comment: I was thinking till now that on function call a server instance will start and on finishing the execution, it will shut down. But looks like its not so. Any documented info on how long the server instance will be available continously?

Comment: No, that is an implementation detail and may change at any time.

Comment: Just an update - I tested in the local emulator and it seems to initialise for every api request. May be i assume this is the case with local emulator but not the production one.

Comment: That behavior of the emulator might change in the future as well.  The emulator does not at all try to duplicate the actual service in this way.